# Second-order PDE with non-constant coefficients: method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have formulated the following PDE during my research:
$$
 \rho(W - K + \delta R)\partial_W U + \mu R\, \partial_R U - \gamma = 0\ ,
$$
where $U = U(W,R)$, and all other symbols in the above are constants. The $\delta R$ term is what is driving me crazy: if it were absent, a solution of the form $a \log{(W-K)} + b \log{(R)}$ would work just fine.

I would be grateful for any ideas on how to go about solving for, or approximating $U$.

**EDIT.** Following the suggestion in the comments, I attempted to apply the  method of characteristics as follows.

I first of all introduce the initial condition $U(0, R) = \log{R}$. I then have the following IVPs:
\begin{alignat}{3}
 \partial_\tau W &= \rho(W - K + \delta R)  \qquad &&W(0, s) &&&= 0\\
 \partial_\tau R &= \mu R  &&R(0, s) &&&= s\\
 \partial_\tau U &= \gamma  &&U(0, s) &&&= \log{s}
\end{alignat}
Solving the IVP for $U$ yields
$$
 U = \gamma \tau + \log{s}\ ,
$$
whereas the IVP for $R$ yields
$$
 R = s \exp{\mu \tau}\ .
$$
Plugging this expression into the IVP for $W$, Mathematica solves it as
$$
 W = \frac{K (\rho -\mu ) \left(e^{\rho  \tau }-1\right)+\delta  \rho  s \left(e^{\mu  \tau }-e^{\rho  \tau }\right)}{\mu -\rho }\ .
$$
Have I proceeded correctly thus far? Is the only remaining step to solve for $\tau$ and $s$ in terms of $R$ and $W$ and plug this back into the expression for $U(\tau, s)$? If so, what does one do if the system cannot be inverted, as is the case here?

Comment: Do you know the method of characteristics?

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks for the tip! Please see the edit.

Comment: In this case unfortunately the best you can do is to invert the equations numerically, I think.

Comment: @K.defaoite Ah that's a shame. But as far as you can see, have I applied the method of characteristics correctly?

Comment: It appears that you have set up the characteristic equations correctly, yes.

Comment: For what it's worth, choosing the simplest possible values for the constants (0s and 1s) that does not alter the structure of the problem, i.e the PDE
$$(x+y)\partial_xu(x,y)+y\partial_yu(x,y)=1 \\ u(0,y)=\log y$$
Mathematica is able to solve this in terms of the Lambert W:
$$u(x,y)=\log(f(x,y))+W\left(\frac{x}{f(x,y)}\right)$$
Where $f(x,y)=\exp\left(\frac{-x+y\log y}{y}\right)$ appears to be some sort of characteristic

Comment: @K.defaoite This is great! I would accept this as an answer if you would briefly elaborate on how I can accomplish the transformation back to the form of the problem above.